# Why is this code running synchronously?

Tags: c#, multithreading, async-await, task-parallel-library, task

I am trying to understand concurrency by doing it in code.  I have a code snippet which I thought was running asynchronously.  But when I put the debug writeline statements in, I found that it is running synchronously.  Can someone explain what I need to do differently to push ComputeBB() onto another thread using Task.Something?

**Clarification**  I want this code to run ComputeBB in some other thread so that the main thread will keep on running without blocking.

Here is the code:

```
{
    // part of the calling method
     Debug.WriteLine("About to call ComputeBB");
     returnDTM.myBoundingBox = await Task.Run(() => returnDTM.ComputeBB());
     Debug.WriteLine("Just called await ComputBB.");
     return returnDTM;
}

  private ptsBoundingBox2d ComputeBB()
  {
     Debug.WriteLine("Starting ComputeBB.");
     Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch(); sw.Start();
     var point1 = this.allPoints.FirstOrDefault().Value;
     var returnBB = new ptsBoundingBox2d(
        point1.x, point1.y, point1.z, point1.x, point1.y, point1.z);
     Parallel.ForEach(this.allPoints,
        p => returnBB.expandByPoint(p.Value.x, p.Value.y, p.Value.z)
        );
     sw.Stop();
     Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("Compute BB took {0}", sw.Elapsed));
     return returnBB;
  }
```

Here is the output in the immediate window:

```
About to call ComputeBB
Starting ComputeBB.
Compute BB took 00:00:00.1790574
Just called await ComputBB.
```

**Clarification**  If it were really running asynchronously it would be in this order:

```
About to call ComputeBB
Just called await ComputBB.
Starting ComputeBB.
Compute BB took 00:00:00.1790574
```

But it is not.

**Elaboration**
The calling code has signature like so:        private static async Task loadAsBinaryAsync(string fileName)  At the next level up, though, I attempt to stop using async.  So here is the call stack from top to bottom:

```
  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
      aTinFile = ptsDTM.CreateFromExistingFile("TestSave.ptsTin");
      // more stuff
  }

  public static ptsDTM CreateFromExistingFile(string fileName)
  {
     ptsDTM returnTin = new ptsDTM();
     Task<ptsDTM> tsk = Task.Run(() => loadAsBinaryAsync(fileName));
     returnTin = tsk.Result;  // I suspect the problem is here.
     return retunTin;
  }

  private static async Task<ptsDTM> loadAsBinaryAsync(string fileName)
  {
      // do a lot of processing
     Debug.WriteLine("About to call ComputeBB");
     returnDTM.myBoundingBox = await Task.Run(() => returnDTM.ComputeBB());
     Debug.WriteLine("Just called await ComputBB.");
     return returnDTM;
  }
```

Comment: please not that *async.* operations don't have to run on separate threads and that multithreaded programs are not necessarily async. There is a difference between those concepts.

Comment: Thank you Carsten.  My question is, then, what more do I need to do to make it be on another thread?

Comment: overall I think you just want to remove the `await` and the code will behave as expected (you need to do nothing `Task.Run` will start it on a new thread - the problem is your await: here you say: "stop my thread and resume it as soon as the `Task` you started with `Task.Run` produces it's result" - that is why it look sync. to you

Comment: This is similar to what Yuval suggested, but I tried it again.  I still get the same ordering of Debug statements indicating that it is still running synchronously.

Comment: no I think your code is just to fast - but a `Thread.Sleep` into `ComputeBB`´ and retry - also please note that I cannot see the signature of your calling function - it seemed like you did use `async` on it - if so you should strip it as well as you don't really seem to want it (you can let it and your code will still run on a different thread but I think you just want to experiment and I would start without `async/await`)

Comment: also you could try to run it in *Release* ;)

Comment: The problem may be in my function signature, not at this level, but higher.  I will add more clarification to the original question momentarily so others can see it and hopefully help me there.

Comment: just to clarify: the way you do it is fine and works - you just will not observe it differently because you use the await and the new shiny features (async/await) are there to let you program async as if it was sync ;) - maybe add the ManagedThreadId to your traces - you should see the difference then

Comment: I have edited my original post to show the signatures of the methods higher in the call stack.  Please note my comment "I suspect the problem is here."

Comment: Carsten, I took you advice and put thread ids in the debug writeline statements.  They are, in fact, on different threads.  Then I put a thread.sleep(5000); statement in ComputeBB.  The final statement "Just called await ComputBB." still does not appear until ComputeBB returns.  I.e., it is blocking.  How do I unblock it.  I thought /await/ would do that for me.

Comment: no ... await *will* block (or it will seem to block) - that's the point behind async/await - it should look as though you are still doing it sync. so it's easier for you to program/reason about your program - actually it will not block the thread your are in - it will register a callback and continue working (possible on another thread) after your `ComputeBB` returns (the Tasks it returns finishes) - it's hidden from you by the machinery async/await is

Comment: "Blocking" is a very specific term in multi-threading. It means a thread is suspended in execution while it waits for an external signal. Non-blocking code will instead allow you to continue executing while you're waiting for the response (especially important with threadpool threads, which can easily be used for other work in the meantime) - but obviously, you *can't* work with the response until you actually *have* the result. `Task<T>` in this sense represents a promise of a future value - it's not there yet, but you can pass the promise around and attach code that happens when task is done

Comment: I have asked a new question which I think is more general than this one.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30033833/how-do-i-make-non-essential-computations-run-in-the-background  .  I am grateful to everyone for trying to help me on this.  As the discussion developed I realized that I need to ask a more fundamental question, which is why I asked an entirely new one.

Answer (score 8):

> I have a code snippet which I thought was running asynchronously. But when I put the debug writeline statements in, I found that it is running synchronously.

`await` is used to **asynchronously wait** an operations completion. While doing so, it yields control back to the calling method until it's completion.

> what I need to do differently to push ComputeBB() onto another thread

It is already ran on a thread pool thread. If you don't want to asynchronously wait on it in a "fire and forget" fashion, *don't `await` the expression.* Note this will have an effect on exception handling. Any exception which occurs inside the provided delegate would be captured inside the given `Task`, if you don't `await`, there is a chance they will go about unhandled.

**Edit:**

Lets look at this piece of code:

```
public static ptsDTM CreateFromExistingFile(string fileName)
{
   ptsDTM returnTin = new ptsDTM();
   Task<ptsDTM> tsk = Task.Run(() => loadAsBinaryAsync(fileName));
   returnTin = tsk.Result;  // I suspect the problem is here.
   return retunTin;
}
```

What you're currently doing is synchronously blocking when you use `tsk.Result`. Also, for some reason you're calling `Task.Run` twice, once in each method. That is unnecessary. If you want to return your `ptsDTM` instance from `CreateFromExistingFile`, you will have to `await` it, there is no getting around that. "Fire and Forget" execution doesn't care about the result, at all. It simply wants to start whichever operation it needs, if it fails or succeeds is usually a non-concern. That is clearly not the case here.

You'll need to do something like this:

```
private PtsDtm LoadAsBinary(string fileName)
{
   Debug.WriteLine("About to call ComputeBB");
   returnDTM.myBoundingBox = returnDTM.ComputeBB();
   Debug.WriteLine("Just called ComputeBB.");

   return returnDTM;
}
```

And then somewhere up higher up the call stack, you don't actually need `CreateFromExistingFiles`, simply call:

```
Task.Run(() => LoadAsBinary(fileName));
```

When needed.

Also, please, read the [C# naming conventions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229045%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which you're currently not following.

Comment: But I /do/ want it in a "fire and forget" fashion, and I expected this code to do that, but it does not.  My question is, how do I make it fire and forget?

Comment: As I said, remove the `await` operator.

Comment: Thanks.  I am off to try that and I will be back.

Comment: Okay, so I changed my code to this, but the results are still the same in that the method ComputeBB is being called synchronously:             Debug.WriteLine("About to call ComputeBB");
         Task<ptsBoundingBox2d> t = Task.Run(() => returnDTM.ComputeBB());
         returnDTM.myBoundingBox = t.Result;
         Debug.WriteLine("Just called await ComputBB.");

Comment: So let me clarify, your comment, "it yields control back to the calling method until it's completion."  that is exactly what I want it to do and it is not doing it.

Comment: `t.Result ` is a **blocking call**. This will truly synchronously wait on the thread to complete. If you need the value back from the thread, you'll need to `await`. You're not actually doing "fire and forget" here

Comment: Yes, I agree.  That is why in my original code it used the await keyword.  And it still doesn't do fire and forget.

Comment: Are you sure you've read my answer? `await` will not continue on to the next line of code until the underlying `Task` has completed. That doesn't *mean* it's synchronous. You'll experience synchronous like behavior.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76849/discussion-between-philologon-and-yuval-itzchakov).

Comment: Then perhaps I am asking the wrong question. What I really want to do is start that task running, then continue on with the return statement. If await is not how I do that, then what do I need to be looking at? I have read some on TPL, so if you could give a brief explanation, I can go research it the rest of the way.

Comment: @philologon How can you return a value you *don't have yet*? Really, try thinking for a few minutes about what you're trying to do. If you want to *propagate* the asynchronous behaviour, you'll need to make the method return `Task<Whatever>`. But as soon as you try to get the resulting value in any way, you *have to wait for it to be returned*. These are really basic concepts in asynchronous programming, you might want to read a few articles (or books) on the topic. A great intro of course being http://www.albahari.com/threading/

Comment: @philologon The benefit of using `await` is in freeing up the calling thread while the task completes, not in fire and forget or returning the result to the user prematurely. I actually published a [blog post](http://www.ramblingincode.com/await-a-minute-that-isnt-async/) about this very situation just last night.

Answer (score 3):

`await`'s whole purpose is in adding the synchronicity back in asynchronous code. This allows you to easily partition the parts that are happenning synchronously and asynchronously. Your example is absurd in that it never takes any advantage whatsoever of this - if you just called the method directly instead of wrapping it in `Task.Run` and `await`ing that, you would have had the exact same result (with less overhead).

Consider this, though:

```
await
  Task.WhenAll
  (
    loadAsBinaryAsync(fileName1),
    loadAsBinaryAsync(fileName2),
    loadAsBinaryAsync(fileName3)
  );
```

Again, you have the synchronicity back (`await` functions as the synchronization barrier), but you've actually performed three independent operations asynchronously *with respect to each other*.

Now, there's no reason to do something like this in your code, since you're using `Parallel.ForEach` at the bottom level - you're already using the CPU to the max (with unnecessary overhead, but let's ignore that for now).

So the basic usage of `await` is actually to handle asynchronous *I/O* rather than CPU work - apart from simplifying code that relies on some parts of CPU work being synchronised and some not (e.g. you have four threads of execution that simultaneously process different parts of the problem, but at some point have to be reunited to make sense of the individual parts - look at the `Barrier` class, for example). This includes stuff like "making sure the UI doesn't block while some CPU intensive operation happens in the background" - this makes the CPU work asynchronous *with respect to the UI*. But at some point, you still want to reintroduce the synchronicity, to make sure you can display the results of the work on the UI.

Consider this winforms code snippet:

```
async void btnDoStuff_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  lblProgress.Text = "Calculating...";
  var result = await DoTheUltraHardStuff();
  lblProgress.Text = "Done! The result is " + result;
}
```

(note that the method is `async void`, not `async Task` nor `async Task<T>`)

What happens is that (on the GUI thread) the label is first assigned the text `Calculating...`, then the asynchronous `DoTheUltraHardStuff` method is scheduled, and then, the method returns. Immediately. This allows the GUI thread to do whatever it needs to do. *However* - as soon as the asynchronous task is complete and the GUI is free to handle the callback, the execution of `btnDoStuff_Click` will *continue* with the `result` already given (or an exception thrown, of course), back on the GUI thread, allowing you to set the label to the new text including the result of the asynchronous operation.

Asynchronicity is *not* an absolute property - stuff is asynchronous to some other stuff, and synchronous to some other stuff. It only makes sense with respect to some other stuff.

Hopefully, now you can go back to your original code and understand the part you've misunderstood before. The solutions are multiple, of course, but they depend a lot on how and why you're trying to do what you're trying to do. I suspect you don't actually need to use `Task.Run` or `await` at all - the `Parallel.ForEach` already tries to distribute the CPU work over multiple CPU cores, and the only thing you could do is to make sure other code doesn't have to wait for that work to finish - which would make a lot of sense in a GUI application, but I don't see how it would be useful in a console application with the singular purpose of calculating that single thing.

So yes, you *can* actually use `await` for fire-and-forget code - but *only* as part of code that doesn't prevent the code you want to continue from executing. For example, you could have code like this:

```
Task<string> result = SomeHardWorkAsync();
Debug.WriteLine("After calling SomeHardWorkAsync");
DoSomeOtherWorkInTheMeantime();
Debug.WriteLine("Done other work.");

Debug.WriteLine("Got result: " + (await result));
```

This allows `SomeHardWorkAsync` to execute asynchronously with respect to `DoSomeOtherWorkInTheMeantime` but *not* with respect to `await result`. And of course, you can use `await`s in `SomeHardWorkAsync` without trashing the asynchronicity between `SomeHardWorkAsync` and `DoSomeOtherWorkInTheMeantime`.

The GUI example I've shown way above just takes advantage of handling the continuation as something that happens after the task completes, while ignoring the `Task` created in the `async` method (there really isn't much of a difference between using `async void` and `async Task` when you *ignore* the result). So for example, to fire-and-forget your method, you could use code like this:

```
async void Fire(string filename)
{
  var result = await ProcessFileAsync(filename);
  DoStuffWithResult(result);
}

Fire("MyFile");
```

This will cause `DoStuffWithResult` to execute as soon as `result` is ready, while the method `Fire` itself will return immediately after executing `ProcessFileAsync` (up to the first `await` or any explicit `return someTask`).

This pattern is usually frowned upon - there really isn't any reason to return `void` out of an async method (apart from event handlers); you could just as easily return `Task` (or even `Task<T>` depending on the scenario), and let the caller decide whether he wants his code to execute synchronously in respect to yours or not.

Again,

```
async Task FireAsync(string filename)
{
  var result = await ProcessFileAsync(filename);
  DoStuffWithResult(result);
}

Fire("MyFile");
```

does the same thing as using `async void`, except that the caller can decide what to do with the asynchronous task. Perhaps he wants to launch two of those in parallel and continue after all are done? He can just `await Task.WhenAll(Fire("1"), Fire("2"))`. Or he just wants that stuff to happen completely asynchronously with respect to his code, so he'll just call `Fire("1")` and ignore the resulting `Task` (of course, ideally, you at the very least want to handle possible exceptions).

Comment: Luann, you spent a lot of time working on that answer, so I am very grateful to you for that.  From all of the help I have received on this question, I realized that my real question is at a higher level, so I have asked this new question in a new post at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30033833/how-do-i-make-non-essential-computations-run-in-the-background